# Given n numbers and k slots. Such that for each slot it can be either 0, or a number less than the previous number, Combinatorics

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

I have an encoding problem. Given n numbers and k slots. Such that for each slot it can be either 0, or a number less than the previous number. 
E.g.

for n=4,k=4

```
0000, 3000, 3200, 3210 etc.
```

for n=7,k=3

```
000, 700, 541, 731, 540 etc.
```

Could anyone please tell me what the pattern here is, in other words, what is the formula that describes the number of possibilities?

Some python code that illustrates the problem (the code itself is not important, I'm looking for a closed-form of make_encod(n,k))

```
from math import factorial
import math

def make_encod(n,k):
    tol=[""]
    for i in range(0,k):
        tol=make_strin_from_tile(0,max(n-i,1),tol)
    print(len(tol))
    print(tol)


def make_strin_from_tile(f,t,all):
    a=[]
    for b in all:
        for i in range(f,t):
            if len(b)==0 or int(b[-1])>i or int(b[-1])==0==i:
                a.append(f"{b}{i}")
    return a
#just some examples
print(make_encod(3,1))
print(make_encod(3,2))
print(make_encod(3,3))
print(make_encod(5,4))
```

Would output:

```
> 3
['0', '1', '2']
None
4
['00', '10', '20', '21']
None
4
['000', '100', '200', '210']
None
16
['0000', '1000', '2000', '2100', '3000', '3100', '3200', '3210', '4000', '4100', '4200', '4210', '4300', '4310', '4320', '4321']
None
```

I am looking for a formula that tells me the answer for make_encod(n,k))? There must be something smarter then actually going through this

Comment: You want number of possibilities or the whole list of possibilities ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut just the number e.g. a formula that tells me how many there will be

Comment: Is this even a programming related question? Sounds more like a case for the Math stack exchange

Comment: @SwimmerF isince since it is combinatorics specifically i assumed it would fall under computer science aswell

Comment: Shouldn't `make_encod(3,3)` give `000
100
110
111
200
210
211
220
221
222` @SLuck

Comment: @Ch3steR no, it should be strictly less then the previous number(or 0)

Comment: @SLuck I did it with recursive function is it fine?

Comment: @Ch3steR sounds like a great start

Comment: @SLuck Check answer I posted.

Comment: This seems more of a maths question than a coding question. https://math.stackexchange.com/ might be more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the conditions correctly, this question maps to

> What is the number of combinations to pick *up to k* elements from a set of *n* distinct numbers

Because you can get all legal combinations by crossing out all but *k or less* from the ordered set [ n, n-1, n-2 ... 1] and then fill up any remaining slots with zeroes.

The number of k or less objects from a set of n is

```
( n! / n! ) + ( n! / (n-1)! ) + ... + ( n! / (n-k)! ) 
= sum_(i=0)^k (n!)/((n - i)!)
```

For which I currently can't tell the explicit formula. I might come back to try to solve it later, but anyone more adept at solving sums than me is welcome to do so.

*Disclaimer: I never did Math in English, so excuse me if some of my vocabulary is off*

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541272/given-n-numbers-and-k-slots-such-that-for-each-slot-it-can-be-either-0-or-a-nu/3541330#3541330 more detailed version

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Recursive Function* here.

```
def recur(lst,ln,curr='a'):
     if ln==len(curr[1:]):
         print(curr[1:])
         return
     else:
         for i in lst:
             if curr[-1]>i or i=='0':
                 recur(lst,ln,curr+i)
```

Why I used `'a'` as initial `curr` is because of `all('a'>str(i) for i in range(10))= True`.

---

```
a=[str(i) for i in range(3)] #['0','1','2']
recur(a,1)
#0 1 2
recur(a,2)
00 10 20 21
recur(a,3)
000 100 200 210
b=[str(i) for i in range(5)] #['0','1','2','3','4']
recur(b,4)
0000 1000 2000 2100 3000 3100 3200 3210 4000 4100 4200 4210 4300 4310 4320 4321
```

Comment: nice function, was more looking for the mathematical approach though, I assume there must be an easy solution

Comment: @SLuck Agreed, Mathematical solution is always faster than iterative one. Mind upvoting?